# Error when flagging user on Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

While attempting to flag a user on Stack Overflow Careers, I receive an error message. Resume that I attempted to execute this on: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/jobs/146545/candidates#!/resume/1255673

[image: dialog and data]

Comment: @darren thanks for the report! We'll look into this and get back to you.